# How to debug boost::bind and boost::signals2::signal::connect errors with unmatched callback function?

Tags: c++, boost

When you try to `connect` a method or function that doesn't match the `signal`s type you get an error. The problem is that the error is rather confusing and does not originate in your code - so with multiple `connect` call, I can't even tell which one is causing it.

```
../libs/boost159/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:57: error: no match for call to '(boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (DataPoint::*)(DataPointMgr&, bool), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<DataPoint*>, boost::arg<1> > >) (const std::basic_string<char>&)'
           BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN((*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
```

So, I'm not asking someone to fix my specific problem. I want to know how to properly and quickly troubleshoot these errors so the next time I forget an asterisk or swap data types it won't take 20 minutes to figure out.

Comment: answer would be very helpful